# Random number generator in VHDL

Tags: random, vhdl

I'm designing a test bench and I need to create a random sequence of bits for one of the system's inputs which is normally controlled by the user.
I also want this sequence of bits not being in the same order every time I run the simulation.

I cannot use a PRNG since its initial state will be predefined meaning it while produce the same numbers every time. I also used the uniform function but I had the same issue.

```
RAND_GEN : process(clk) is
    variable seed1, seed2 : positive := 1;
    variable re           : real;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        uniform(seed1, seed2, re);
        if (re < 0.5) then
            rand_bit <= '0';
        else
            rand_bit <= '1';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Is there any alternatives for this problem?

Comment: *" also want this sequence of bits not being in the same order every time I run the simulation."* Yes you do, otherwise you can not find any error which appears. You might want to be able the *change* the sequence from run to run.

Comment: on Linux, you can read random bytes from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 G.1.4 Use and constraints of pseudo-random number generator in MATH_REAL "The pseudo-random number generator provided with the package is platform independent. In order to generate a chain of pseudo-random numbers, the seed values shall be set only in the first call to the function. A different chain of numbers is started every time the seed values are set. If multiple chains of pseudo-random numbers are required, then different sets of seed values have to be used for every chain."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing with randomly generated inputs is a powerful tehnique and is the technique commonly used to verify ICs these days. Normally, you would run a test with a known, per-determined seed, whereas you want to be able to generate a varying seed. So, you absolutely MUST record this seed when you run the test and provide a mechanism to run a test using this seed. Otherwise, when you find a bug, you will not be able to test whether you've fixed it. You might find it more useful to a a fixed set of tests with a smaller number of manually-generated seeds.

You could use the linux `date` command with the `%s` format specifier, which outputs the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 and redirect that to a file.

```
date +%s >! seed.txt
```

Then read the file, eg:

```
RAND_GEN : process(clk) is
    variable seed1, seed2 : positive := 1;
    variable re           : real;
    file F: TEXT;
    variable L: LINE;
    variable seed_RNG : boolean := false;
begin
    if not seed_RNG then
        file_open(F, "seed.txt", READ_MODE);
        readline (F, L);
        read (L, seed1);  -- or seed2
        file_close(F);
        report "seed1 = " & integer'image(seed1);
        seed_RNG := true;
    end if;
    if rising_edge(clk) then    
        uniform(seed1, seed2, re);
        if (re < 0.5) then
            rand_bit <= '0';
        else
            rand_bit <= '1';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I had a similar idea but searching for a vhdl function that returns the current time for testing purposes I found nothing.

Is there any way to automate this procedure?
Can this file, for example, be refreshed after some time?

Comment: There won't be a command for finding out the wallclock time in VHDL. There is no construct for running OS commands from VHDL, either. (There is in SystemVerilog - `$system`.) You could set up a unix cron (?) job to refresh the file from time to time, but surely the easiest way is to start your simulation from a script and execute the `date` command in that script.

Comment: If your undisclosed simulator has the implementation dependent ability to provide top level generics (e.g. Modelsim, ghdl, Aldec), as command line arguments you pass the seed values in. Note that the seed values should be constrained SEED1 <= 2147483562 and SEED2 <= 2147483398 and are type integer. See package math_real. You could use an external program or script providing a constrained integer value literal (here) for most host operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything of VHDL, but in general I try to avoid randomness in tests. Flaky unit tests, for example, are bad. What's the value of a test that fails only sometimes?

Anyway, supposed you really want to do it, do you have access to a timer? You can initialize the PRNG with the current time as seed. Not cryptographically safe, but probably for this use case good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, in case anyone needs something similar, I used the above ideas by creating a do file which first writes the date in a file and then runs the do file of the actual test bench which reads this number as suggested before.

```
set t [clock seconds]
set outputFile [open date.txt w]
puts $outputFile $t
close $outputFile 
do testbench.do
```